# Where to find Windows Updates catalogs?

Tags: windows, updates, catalog

Is it possible to get the list of the latest updates for all windows versions? Where? For example which was the latest security update launched for windows 8.1?

there is ([Microsoft Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com)) but, its no so friendly concerning to search.